# Get total rows and last id in one query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to get the count() and the value of a column for the last (read: highest numeric value) row in one SQL query?

For example:

```
SELECT count(id), last(id) FROM `table` WHERE date = '20200611' and time BETWEEN '18:15' and '18:20'
```

My goal is to get the total of rows and remember the last id to start counting from that row on the next time, when the only thing that is given is the data and time interval. Something like:

```
SELECT count(id), last(id) FROM `table` WHERE date = '20200611' and time BETWEEN '18:20' and '18:25' and id > remembered_id_value
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if id is autoincrement you  could use max

```
SELECT count(id), max(id) 
FROM `table` 
WHERE date = '20200611' 
and time BETWEEN '18:15' and '18:20'
```